# Can I bind query from WIQL to dataviewer/grid?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, wiql

I have this code that outputs the results to a textbox

```
 try
        {
            // Connect to the work item store
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
                  new Uri("xxx"));
            WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tpc.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));

            // Run a query.
            WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(richTextBox1.Text);

            foreach (WorkItem workItem in queryResults)
            {

               richTextBox2.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, workItem.AreaPath, workItem.Project);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exceptionmessage)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exceptionmessage.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Can I treat the query result as I would a SQL query from SQL Server and bind it to a datagrid or dataviewer? I can't seem to get this to work, I don't understand how the data is handled and returned from WIQL/TFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to get the query result and place them into a table in a dataset, and then bind the dataset to datagrid. Refer to this article for details:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briancombs/archive/2006/09/19/762210.aspx

Comment: Thank you this worked! Any more info on how the query results look like?

Comment: What do you mean about how the query results look like?

Comment: Is it a table? Looks like the code iterates the results and checks the Column name against the result. I'm just curious why this doesn't work like how you would query a database using T-SQL and SQL Server for example.

Comment: The query result from WIQL is a collection of workitems, not a table. So the code need to iterate the result to create a table and then place the created table in dataset.

Comment: Thank you!!! I feel like I've been trying to jam a square shape into a triangle hole. This makes sense. I appreciate it.